# Cuando hago asincrona una funcion recibo el error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object Promise])

Tags: javascript, reactjs, nextjs

Tengo un componente que recibe un array con objetos. Estos objetos pueden tener un `type` y depende de esto, deberian renderizar diferentes componentes.

Me sucede que el `type: reviews` necesita hacer unas verificaciones y dependendiendo de estas, llamadas a diferentes APIs.

Entonces como tengo que trabajar con datos asincronos, necesito que la funcion sea asincrona. Quiero poder hacer, dentro de mi funcion `renderComponents`, en el `case "reviews":` del switch, un `const data = await getReviews(element);` y para esto necesito que la funcion `renderComponents` sea asincrona.

El tema es que al momento que le agrego `async` recibo el error:

> Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object Promise]). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

El error lo recibo aun comentando el `case "reviews"`, cuando agrego la palabra `async` a la funcion. Si quito la palabra `async` todo funciona bien.

Probe haciendo este tipo de funcion y tambien funciones flecha, pero el error persiste.

```
async function renderComponents(element) {
    // si dejo la palabra async recibo el error,
    // si la quito, todo se ve bien. Pero no puedo ejecutar mi
    // funcion getReviews
    const type = element.sys?.contentType?.sys?.id || null;
    if (type) {
      switch (type) {
        case "buttonOrLink":
          return <p>Component for buttonOrLink</p>;
          
        case "copyImagegridSection":
          return <p>Component for copyImagegridSection</p>;

        case "explore":
          return <p>Component for explore</p>;

        case "video":
          return (
            <LightBox
              content={element.fields.videoThumbnail?.fields?.file?.url}
              video={element.fields}
            />
          );

        // case "reviews":
          // const data = await getReviews(element);
          // console.log(data);
          // break;

        default:
          return;
      }
    }
    return;
  }

  return (
    <>
      Page Section
      {content.map(el => {
        return (
          <div key={el.sys.id}>
            {renderComponents(el)}
          </div>
          
        );
      })}
      {offers.length > 0 && <Specials content={offers} />}
      {faqs.length > 0 && <FAQ faqs={faqs} />}
    </>
  );
```

**EDIT**

Una cosa que me pasa, que no entiendo pero tal vez pueda servir para que alguien se dé cuenta, es que si yo descomento este bloque

```
          // case "reviews":
          // const data = getReviews(element);
          // console.log(data);
          // break;
```

Sin hacer la funcion `renderComponents` asincrona, y colocando un console.log en la funcion `getReviews()`, cuando se carga la pagina, primero se imprime el console.log(data) con `Promise {<pending>}` y luego se imprime el console de getReviews mostrando los datos correctos.

Comment: ¿Será porque estas regresando un Objeto tipo Promise al usar async?

Comment: Si no devuelvo nada pero le coloco la palabra ``async`` de todas maneras recibo el error. Hasta donde yo sé, lo que no puede ser async es un componente, o la funcion que le pasas a un hook, pero ``renderComponents`` es una funcion pura, no un componente... o al menos eso intenté hacer

Comment: En el caso `reviews` imagino que vas a regresar un elemento, por ejemplo en otros casos tienes elementos como `<Lightbox>` o `<p>`, porque el error nos dice que los objetos no son validos como react childrens, pero no se ve que es lo que intentas regresar en `reviews` ¿Supongo que vas a regresar algo parecido a `<Lightbox>` o `<p>`?

Comment: claro, el tema es que al componente <Reviews /> necesito pasarle datos que tengo que ir a pedir a una API, entonces yo tengo la funcion que es asincrona y funciona bien para traer las reviews. El tema es que si yo la llamo desde ``renderComponents`` haciendo algo como ``const data = getReviews()`` a continuacion ``return <Reviews reviews={data} />``, a mi componente ``Reviews`` llega una promesa pendiente.

Comment: `data` es efectivamente una Promesa. No conozco React a profundidad, pero siendo que se trata de Javascript, me pregunto si usar `then` encadenado a `getReviews` te funcionaría, algo como: `getReviews(elements).then(data => { ... } );`. Saludos

Comment: @MauricioContreras gracias, me sirvio pero en cierto aspecto, es decir, si hago ``.then(data => console.log(data) );`` puedo ahora ver que la data llega, pero si yo intento guardar ese valor, ya sea haciendo ``const respuesta = getReviews(elements).then(data => data );`` o bien definiendo una variable ``respuesta`` en null y haciendo ``getReviews(elements).then(data => respuesta = data);``, el problema es el mismo, dentro del then tengo el resultado esperado, pero cuando lo quiero devolver en un return una linea despues, ese valor es una promesa pendiente.

Comment: Eso no lo podrás hacer, a menos que el entorno en el cual quieras recibir esa respuesta sea asíncrono. Tal parece que no lo es, por lo cual, no tendrías acceso inmediato a esta variable. Podrías usar una solicitud no asíncrona, pero esto sería bloqueante, pausando todo el proceso hasta que la solicitud `http` se complete.

Comment: Finalmente para solucionarlo tuve que cambiar el enfoque. Al montarse el componente seteé un ``loading`` en ``true`` y creé una funcion (ahora si, asincrona) que va cargando un array de estado con cada elemento, el tipo de elemento, y el orden en el que llega (ya que acá se guardan desordenados). Es acá donde puedo, sin problemas, hacer un ``await`` y obtener los datos de la API (llamando a getReviews). Cuando termino de recibir todo y armar el array, lo ordeno, pongo ``loading`` en ``false`` y finalmente imprimo el array ordenado.

Comment: Bueno al parecer ya lo has solucionado. Solo me preguntaba si en vez de llamar a  getReviews dentro del case, llamases una funcion en la parte superior que sea asincrona y alli ejecutar  getReviews y asi evitar que renderComponents sea asincrona. Otra pregunta, ¿que sucede en estos casos cuando nadie responde a una pregunta con recompensa?¿ se devuelve la recompensa al ofertante?

Comment: Eso mismo tenia al momento de preguntar, pero el tema es que si bien la funcion que se llama (getReviews) es asincrona, si yo no puedo hacer asincrona a la funcion encargada de llamar (renderComponents) no puedo esperar el resultado de getReviews. Los puntos que no se dan de recompensa se pierden. Saludos!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Problema

El problema es que React espera que el componente devuelva un elemento o un array de elementos, y no una promesa o funciones asíncronas. En tu caso, la función `renderComponents` debería devolver un elemento de React síncrono, y luego manejar la lógica asíncrona **dentro** de ese componente.

## Enfoque de solución

Una manera de hacerlo es utilizar el estado del componente para almacenar el resultado de la promesa y actualizarlo una vez que se resuelva.
Si usamos el hook `useEffect` para manejar la lógica de obtener los datos, entonces, en el componente `Reviews`, puedes tener un estado inicial vacío para los datos, y usar `useEffect` para hacer la llamada a la API y actualizar el estado con los datos devueltos.

```
const Reviews = ({ element }) => {
    const [reviews, setReviews] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        getReviews(element).then(data => setReviews(data));
    }, [element]);

    if (!reviews) {
        return <p>Cargando...</p>;
    }

    // Acá tocaría renderizar componente con los datos
    return <div>...</div>;
};
```

Luego, la función `renderComponents` te quedaría algo así:

```
function renderComponents(element) {
    const type = element.sys?.contentType?.sys?.id || null;
    if (type) {
        switch (type) {
            ...
            case "reviews":
                return <Reviews element={element} />;
            ...
```

(Donde hay ... significa código omitido)